# tail reopen file when directory changes

Tags: symlink, tail, inotify

I've got a symlink pointing to the "latest" directory, and I want to tail a file in the latest directory, even if the symlink changes to a newly created directory.  I often use `tail -F` for files and it works fine as inotify tells `tail` when to reopen the file, but in this case, inotify doesn't notice the change so I expect tail to check again after 5 seconds of the second-latest file being unchanged.  (5 seconds according to the tail manpage and the defaults for `--sleep-interval=1.0` and `--max-unchanged-stats=5`.)

```
tail -F --max-unchanged-stats=1 -s 1 /tmp/latest/behaviour
ln -sfT /tmp/2019-02-14-10-15-12 /tmp/latest
```

How can I tail the file in the latest directory?